# How to correctly use title attribute in stylesheet link tags

Tags: html

Can someone describe in detail what the `title` attribute is for when added to a stylesheet `<link>` tag in the `<head>` of my HTML page?  Playing around with some HTML today and while `<link>`ing to multiple stylesheets, I noticed that I seem to be misusing the `title` attribute in my `<link>`s.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/css/foundation.min.css" title="Foundation">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/css/icomoon.css" title="IcoMoon">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome <span class="icon-home"></span>!</h1>
        <!-- scripts -->
        <script src="/static/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/foundation.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

As I started working I was frustrated because my `icomoon.css` stylesheet wasn't loading.  It took me a while to realize that the `title` attribute was the issue.  Specifically, if I removed the `title` attribute from both stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/css/foundation.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/css/icomoon.css">
```

Or if I gave them the same title:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/css/foundation.min.css" title="Foundation">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/css/icomoon.css" title="Foundation">
```

My styles loaded correctly.  After a little bit more investigating, I found that Firefox allows users to select which styles they see by going to `View` -> `Page Style`.  For example, I could make two stylesheets, one called "Boring" and one called "Cool" and the user can switch between the two styles.

That being said, I still am not sure what the purpose of the `title` attribute is?  Mostly because Chrome and Safari (I haven't checked Edge or Internet Explorer) don't seem to have the same functionality to switch between titled styles like Firefox does and because that would seem to me something that should relate more to whether or not a `<link>`'s `rel` attribute includes the `alternate` indicator.  It clearly is not just a convenience attribute to give my stylesheets a nice title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [W3C website](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element):

> The **title** attribute gives the title of the link. With one exception,
>   it is purely advisory. The value is text. The exception is for **style
>   sheet links**, where the **title** attribute defines alternative style sheet
>   sets.

A definition of alternative style sheet sets can be found in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets). Apparently, it's a Firefox-only feature.

Comment: So I guess there wasn't much else to what I already had!  Strange that other browsers don't support switching between named styles.

Comment: What's strange is that, 4 years later, Firefox is *still* the only browser that supports this feature.  The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets) says IE 8+ also has support, but it doesn't seem to be working in IE11.  ([screenshot FF & IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqyHP.png))

Comment: The interesting thing here is that Chrome is *aware* of alternative stylesheets, it just doesn't support switching! If Chrome really didn't support alternative stylesheets, then adding a title tag to the stylesheet wouldn't have any effect and it would just apply all the styles. But while Chrome is loading all the stylesheets, it only applies the first title, ignoring the others/alternates.